# Media Player Button Is Not Restarting

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wanna make "Play/Stop" button. When button "Play" is clicked, the song must be played and its text should be converted into "Stop" and when "Stop" is clicked, the button text should be changed into "Play" again and song should start again to play from the beginning.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_playStop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean flag = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Play Music");

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.zara_sa);
        btn_playStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play_stop);


        btn_playStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && flag==true){
                    stopSong();
                }
                else if (flag == false){
                    playSong();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void playSong(){
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn_playStop.setText("Stop");
        flag = true;
    }
    public void stopSong() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        btn_playStop.setText("Play");
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not capitalize every letter? It hurts my eyes.

Comment: @shtolik
Okay done

Answer (score 0):

You must call `mediaPlayer.prepare();` if you called `mediaPlayer.stop();` so in the first time you can just call `mediaPlayer.start();` but in the next times you should call `mediaPlayer.prepare();` before `mediaPlayer.start();`

```
public void playSong(){
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    btn_playStop.setText("Stop");
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: It's throwing  java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

Comment: i had a mistake, i edited my answer. in the first time you shoudn't call prepare() because the mediaPlayer is already prepared, you should call prepare only after you called stop.

Comment: If I've added this code
 public void stopSong() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        btn_playStop.setText("Play");
        flag = false;
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

After this song keeps playing.
And If I remove mediaPlayer.start(); from this method then it's actually resuming the song.
I have to "Stop" the song and start from the beginning.

Comment: can you say again what happens if you try the code i wrote? i didn't understand.

Comment: Your code is throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

Comment: I'm adding this code
`public void playSong() {
mediaPlayer.start();
btn_playStop.setText("Stop");
flag = true;
}

public void stopSong() {
mediaPlayer.stop();
btn_playStop.setText("Play");
flag = false;
try {
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    btn_playStop.setText("Play");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}`

But now I want to restart the song from the beginning.